# Should django health-check endpoint /ht/ be accessible from everybody?

Tags: django, security

From the documentation reported [here](https://django-health-check.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/)  I read

> This project checks for various conditions and provides reports when
> anomalous behavior is detected.The following health checks are bundled
> with this project:  cache, database,  storage,  disk and memory
> utilization (viapsutil),  AWS S3 storage,  Celery task queue,  Celery
> ping,  RabbitMQ,  Migrations

and from use case section

> The primary intended use case is to monitor conditions via HTTP(S),
> with responses available in HTML and JSONformats. When you get back a
> response that includes one or more problems, you can then decide the
> appropriate courseof action, which could include generating
> notifications and/or automating the replacement of a failing node with
> a newone

And then

> The /ht/ endpoint will respond aHTTP 200 if all checks passed and a HTTP
> 500 if any of the tests failed.

From a security point of view: should this url (https://example.com/ht) be reachable from everybody? It seems to give away different information.

Comment: Are you exposing this endpoint to internet? If yes, then you need to check for the output of the end point for IPaddresses and port numbers or some other sensitive info you are exposing. As long as those are fine, it is okay.

Comment: I found it In a website I'm testing. It shows cachebackend and databasebackend status. But I don't know if when some problem arises it produce sensitive output. 
As I previously reported from the documentation: "provides reports when anomalous behavior is detected."

Comment: what exactly is "reports" here?